# How to pass Argument to method with '#selector'

Tags: swift, selector, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to pass `UIBarButtonItem` as argument, 
but I get the following error:

> Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property,
>   or initializer

```
@objc func barClicked( sender: AnyObject) {

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let bar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50))
    bar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    bar.items = [
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(barClicked(sender: bar.items[0])))]
    bar.sizeToFit()
}
```

Also tried `#selector(barClicked(sender: bar.items[0] as AnyObject`

Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at the "Related" section, this has been asked and answered repeatedly. You *cannot* pass arguments in the selector.

Comment: FYI - The button will be the argument. You don't need to specify it yourself.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, Is there an alternative to solve this?

Comment: Did you read the "Related" questions and their answers?

Comment: You should read the documentation for `UIControl` and the section on "The Target-Action Mechanism". It applies to `UIBarButtonItem` as well.

Comment: @rmaddy    `The button will be the argument.` Now I get it! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never *ever* pass arguments to the method you are referring to when using the `#selector` literal. The argument(s) will be passed to the method by the performer of the selector, which in this case, is the inner workings of `UIBarButtonItem`.

To solve this, simply remove the argument list:

```
#selector(barClicked)
```

When the selector is performed, the `sender` parameter will most likely hold a reference to the second `UIBarButtonItem` in the tool bar, since you are setting the selector as the `action` for the second `UIBarButtonItem`.

However, t seems like that you deliberately want the sender to be the first `UIBarButtonItem` of the toolbar. This sounds quite counter-intuitive. You might be doing something wrong here. But if you insist on passing the first item of the tool bar, do this:

```
// add a new method like this:
func someMethod() { // name this properly!
    barClicked(sender: bar.items[0]) // please make bar a class-level variable first.
}
```

Then you can refer to `someMethod` with `#selector`:

```
#selector(someMethod)
```